# pass a random generated variable to setInterval

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

I have animated a dynamic created element with setInterval. When the element is clicked I want it to change to a random direction (left, right, up or down).

I *think* the problem is that I can´t pass the randomly created direction into the setInterval function.

The html here....

```
<div id="klicker"></div>
```

The JavaScript here.....

```
var box = document.getElementById("klicker");
var x = 1;
var startp = 200;
box.onclick = function() {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.style.width = 200 + 'px';
    newdiv.style.height = 200 + 'px';
    newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = startp + "px";
    newdiv.style.top = startp + "px";
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'runner')
    var run = document.getElementById('runner');
    var dire = 'right';
    run.onclick = function() {
        var mov = function() {
            randoms();
        };
        function randoms() {
            alert('ddddd');
            var rnd = (Math.random() * 4) + 1; //ranom number 1-4
            var rnd_down = Math.floor(rnd); //make it en integer
            /*--- make each number a uniqe direction---*/
            if (rnd_down == 1) {
                dire = 'right';
            } else if (rnd_down == 2) {
                dire = 'left';
            } else if (rnd_down == 3) {
                dire = 'up';
            } else {
                dire = 'down';
            }
        };

        var moveit = setInterval(function() {
            movefunc();
        }, 50);

        function movefunc() {
            /*----each direction will make the div travel in diffrent directions--*/
            if (dire = 'right') {
                x = x + 1;
                newdiv.style.left = x + 'px';
            } else if (dire = 'left') {
                x = x - 1;
                newdiv.style.left = x + 'px';
            } else if (dire = 'up') {
                x = x - 1;
                newdiv.style.top = x + 'px';
            } else {
                x = x + 1;
                newdiv.style.top = x + 'px';
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: `var dire` scope is within `box.onclick` handler only. It will not be available in `movefunc`.

Comment: Second click on `box` would generate a div with duplicate `id = 'runner'`.

Comment: `var newdiv` scope is within `box.onclick` handler only. It will not be available in `movefunc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function movefunc() {
            /*----each direction will make the div travel in diffrent directions--*/
            if (dire = 'right') {
                x = x + 1;
                newdiv.style.left = x + 'px';
            } else if (dire = 'left') {
                x = x - 1;
                newdiv.style.left = x + 'px';
            } else if (dire = 'up') {
                x = x - 1;
                newdiv.style.top = x + 'px';
            } else {
                x = x + 1;
                newdiv.style.top = x + 'px';
            }
        };
```

Rookie mistake :) ( even though it's one of the [most common error in programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/common.html), see #4 ) In your condition, you should use `==` and not `=` ( which is meant for assignation, `==` is made for comparison ). I'd even suggest you to use `===` which will also compare the types. ( `1 == '1'` will return `true` while `1 === '1'` will return `false` cause 1 is an `integer` type, and '1' is a `char` type )

Comment: Yoda style should he use: `'left' == dire`. Give him corrected code snippet you must.

Comment: `if(dire.length > 0 && 'left' === dire) `

Better check if dire isnt empty first. And triple equals. Programmers paranoïd habits must be passed into new padawans.